# Pandas to remove value if it exists in any other column in the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ["dog", "cat", "bird"], 'c2': ["rabbit", "rat", "snake"], 'c3': ["dog", "fish", "snake"]})
```

It looks like:

[image]

Whenever a value in c3 appears in the same row in any other column, I want to update the c3 value to be a blank. Like this:

[image]

Here's what I have tried:

```
df["c3"] = df.apply(lambda x: x if x.c1 or x.c2 not in x.c3 else Nan, axis = 1)
```

But this throws an error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'numpy.int64' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Series.value_counts()` + `.apply`:

```py
df["c3"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: "" if x.value_counts()[x["c3"]] > 1 else x["c3"], axis=1
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     c1      c2    c3
0   dog  rabbit      
1   cat     rat  fish
2  bird   snake
```

Comment: x.value_counts() sees if the value in c3 exists more than 1 time across that row. if it does, it assigns "" or else keeps it at the original value. Cool. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach based on testing equality across columns and replacing with `np.where`:

```
df['c3'] = np.where(df[df.drop('c3', axis=1).columns].eq(df['c3'], axis=0).any(axis=1), 
                    "", df['c3'])
```

```
     c1      c2    c3
0   dog  rabbit      
1   cat     rat  fish
2  bird   snake
```

Comment: I'm assuming that using numpy will be a faster if this becomes a much larger dataset.

Comment: @SMJune only issue here is that its not dynamic, you'd have to hardcode all the rules.

Comment: @Umar.H not sure that's an issue when only 1 column needs to be specified

Comment: @PaulH you're right! how silly of me, nice answer Brendan